# If there is a tab in an application for teacher to be able to input test score for his students, what would the tab called?

Tags: word-request

So I'm developing an app for teachers. One of the tab in the app is allowing teachers to browse as well as input students test and homework scores. I don't know what the term for this activity should be called.

"Marking"? Sounds like someone drawing on white board?

"Scoring"? Sounds like for music notes?

"Evaluation"? I thought this term is more appropriate for the test itself, not the score from the test?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: "Scoring" for me doesn't sound like for music notes for me. In fact, I think it suits the intent of what the teacher needs to do here the most, and also it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the application is for teachers and students of some schools, universities or colleges where subjects like Math, Science, English and so on are taught. If I'm right in this way, it's **obvious** that whatever *label* you give to any tab in the application would be considered of that field only. So, if you label it as 'scoring,' there's **no chance** that someone would expect it to be [a *notch, scratch, or incision.*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scoring)

That said, if the application is for teachers and students, whatever you write -marking, scoring, evaluation, it'll be surely understood of question papers or tests and nothing else.

In my opinion, *grades/scores/marks* will do the job. I may not put -ing.

Note: It also depends on the region you live in. For instance, a decade back, India used *marks* which is now gradually leaning toward *grades* in schools.

Comment: Ah, "grades" ! I think that's the word I'm searching for! For me, it sounds the most appropriate and widely used for this case. Thanks!